# Rust Error conversion for generic FromStr, unwrap errors out with unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: rust

I am using the [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/1.0.24/thiserror/index.html) crate to create a custom error type

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

/// ParseTreeError enumerates all possible errors returned by this library.
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum ParseTreeError {
    /// Represents an empty source. For example, an empty text file being given
    /// as input to `count_words()`.
    #[error("Source contains no data")]
    EmptySource,

    /// Represents a failure to read from input.
    #[error("Read error")]
    ReadError,
}
```

```rust
pub struct Parser <'a, T>
where
    T: FromStr + PartialEq
{
    token_stream: &'a str,
    marker: (usize, usize),
}

impl<'a, T> Parser<'a, T>
where
    T: FromStr + PartialEq
{
    fn test_parse() -> Result<(), ParseTreeError> {
        let mut val = T::from_str("5").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `unwrap` exists for enum `std::result::Result<T, <T as FromStr>::Err>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/tree/parser.rs:65:40
   |
65 |         let mut val = T::from_str("5").unwrap();
   |                                        ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `std::result::Result<T, <T as FromStr>::Err>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<T as FromStr>::Err: Debug`
```

If I map the error like this

```rust
let mut val2 = T::from_str("5").map_err(|_| ParseTreeError::ReadError).unwrap();
```

Then no error is thrown.

If i try to use the ? operator i get the error

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `ParseTreeError`
  --> src/tree/parser.rs:65:40
   |
65 |         let mut val1 = T::from_str("5")?;
   |                                        ^ the trait `From<<T as FromStr>::Err>` is not implemented for `ParseTreeError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = note: required by `from`
```

What do I need to do so that the ? operator can automatically convert the error to the correct error type without having to use map_err ?

Comment: To unwrap, you can add a `T::Err: Debug` bound. To convert with `?`, you can use the `#[from]` annotation as explained in the thiserror docs.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Thanks for the suggestion, what does T::Err mean ? Do all types have it ?

Comment: Also, which error should I use #[from] on, is there a common Error that all FromStr implementations return ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is completely unrelated to `thiserror`, but can be reproduced via

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

fn test_parse<T>() -> Result<(), ()>
where
    T: FromStr,
{
    let mut val = T::from_str("5").unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

So, what's the issue? The issue is hidden away in `Result`'s `unwrap`. `unwrap` is only available if we can [somehow show the `E` in `Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-5):

```rust
//      vvvvvvvvvvvvv
impl<T, E: fmt::Debug> Result<T, E> {
    //    ...
    
    fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        ...
    }
}
```

Where does `E` come from? Well, every `FromStr` implementation has to define the associated error type, `Err`. However, there are no constrains on `Err`. It *might* implement `Debug`, but it also might not. Since our trait bounds on `test_parse` say that we're fine to run over all `T`s that implement just `FromStr`, we're too generic. We need to say that `test_parse` will only work for `T`s that are `FromStr` ***and*** whose associated `Err` type can be shown via `Debug`:

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn test_parse<T>() -> Result<(), ()>
where
    T: FromStr,
    <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug,             // <<<<
{
    let mut val = T::from_str("5").unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

Now `test_parse` cannot be used with all possible `FromStr` implementations anymore, but only those which also implement `Debug` on their associated `Err` type, which is exactly what we needed.

For the `?` operator, we need to implement `From<<T as FromStr>::Err>` for `ParseTreeError`, however, [that's blocked by E0207](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0207).

Comment: What do you mean it is blocked by E0207 ? I looked at the docs, and it seems to suggest a few workarounds.

Comment: Although it seems like they are complicated enough that I have to manually implement them instead of relying on thiserror's #[from] annotation.

Comment: Can I make ParseTreeError Generic to avoid E0207?